# How to implement multiple Devise signin pathways in a single Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'd appreciate some advise on best practice when implementing multiple sign in pathways within a single Rails app.

I'm using Devise, and the usual controllers/ routes are working fine to handle creating/destroying sessions when users visit the app in a browser.

I'm now need to add JS/ iframe plugins to embed limited app functions in external sites. These plugins need to be able to handle sign in, and sign in needs to behave slightly differently than usual - namely using different views for the signin form, and different after_sign_in_path and signed_in_root_path.

Is there a conventional way to handle this behavior?

I considered adding a custom controller that inherits from Devise and sets `devise_mapping`

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :plugins do
  resources :sessions,  only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
end
#controllers/plugins/sessions_controller.rb
class Plugins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    #stuff for my form
  end
  def devise_mapping
    Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
  def after_signin_path
    my_path
  end
end
```

This works OK but seemed like overkill and code duplication. I also could not figure out how to make `signed_in_root_path` aware of whether the app is being used via an embedded plugin or directly.

I could just embed a signin form in a template, pointing to the usual Devise session controller, and pass a `plugin` param on form submit.

```
#application_controller.rb
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope, params)
  if params,has_key?(:plugin)
    #plugin_after_sign_in_path
  else
    #usual_after_sign_in_path
  end
end
```

But this does not seem very clean, requires modifying devise sessions#create to pass the params to `after_sign_in_path_for`, and still does not solve the `signed_in_root` issue.

This situation also has implications elsewhere in the app. For example

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  unless user_signed_in?
    if #we_are_in_the_plugin  
      redirect_to new_plugins_session_url, alert: "You must log in to continue."
    else 
      redirect_to new_user_session_url, alert: "You must log in to continue."
    end
  end
end
```

This has the potential to become almost like maintaining two apps in one, and I can see things becoming complicated with the wrong approach.

There appear to be several ways to achieve multiple signin pathways, and this seems like it should be a reasonably common scenario. So my question is which is the "Rails" way to achieve this - i.e., will be clear to other developers, easily maintainable, and cause less long-term headaches?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to separate the flows and use a custom controller like you have started to do. You could do modify the default controller but it would so get messy when you want to have different sign up flows.

Having it namespaced under plugins/ makes it super easy to understand why the extra controller is there and will make it a lot easier to test. You shouldn't really have much duplicate code either as you'll be inheriting from the devise controller anyway and just adding a private method after_sign_in_path etc. It will also make it easier to render errors differently for the two situations.

EDIT: (additional code)

```
# app/controllers/plugins/sessions_controller.rb
module Plugins
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    def create
      begin
        super
      rescue CanCan::AccessDenied => e
        **handle e here**
      end
    end

    private

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      a_different_signed_in_path
    end
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
namespace :plugins do
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
end
```

Comment: thanks @joe, good to know that I am broadly on the right track. A related question - how would you handle the fact that some methods e.g., `signed_in_root_path` and `rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied` need to behave differently in the plugins. Would you just add private methods to every plugin controller to overwrite these methods, or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: I'm assuming you only need to redirect to the root path after sign in and not have the root path different for plugins. If so you can override the `after_sign_in_path` and use a different path. I'll add some code to the answer to help.

Comment: As for `rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied` that would make sense to do in the PluginSessionsController. Again, I'll put code in the answer.

Comment: thanks @joe, I am now not sure that this approach is possible. Devise seems not to allow two session controllers interacting with the same User model. It refuses to use the plugin views and instead defaults to the usual devise or user views. I'm also struggling to define the post route. Devise appends `/user` if I define the route manually, and create a new `devise_for` in `routes.rb` does not help. Grateful if someone can confirm that they have got Devise working with 2 session controllers, or whether this is a lost cause.